# entitymanager is null on DAO class

Tags: spring, eclipselink

I am trying to implement Spring MVC 3 +EclipseLink JPA 2
When I call saveUser for example it returns that

> NullPointerException, EntityManager is
>   null

:

```
public class UserDAO {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

     @Transactional
    public User saveUser(User user){
        return em.merge(user);
    }
```

My config is:

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>       
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="application" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />

            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="username" value=".." />
    <property name="password" value=".." />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://..." />
</bean>
```

Also have

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.elasticbeanstalk.mypackage" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

It does initialize JPA during Tomcat startup. Why am I see NPE? Could I miss something?

Comment: Can you post code of the service class to where your DAO is being used?

Comment: no I don't have any service class. Just tried from Controller the following UserDAO userDAO =new UserDAO(); User user=new User(); user.setName("name");userDAO.save(user);  Do I have to put something in the middle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you instantiate the `UserDAO` manually, nothing will be injected by Spring. If the DAO is in a package which is under your `base-package` of `<context:component-scan ../>` then you can simply autowire it into your Controller. If not, either modify the base-package or also you can define the DAO in the appcontext manually, then you can autowire as well.

Comment: it does not autowire well without interface, so I created interface,  and it looks good.